# does there exist an integer $m>1$ such that $a+m$ is a divisor of $a^m+1$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a$ be a positive integer that satisfies $a>3$.
>
> 1. Does there exist a positive integer $m$ other than 1 such that: $$a+m \ |\ a^m+1 \ $$ If not, what are the conditions of $a$ for $m$ to exist?
> 2. If there exist such number $m$, are there infinitely many integers $m$ that satisfy $$a+m \ |\ a^m+1 \ $$
>      If not, what are the conditions of $a$ so that there are infinitely many integers $m$ that satisfy the question?

This problem I think might be similar to: Does there exist integer $m>1$ such that: $$m \ |\ a^m+1 \ $$
I have tried to use the Lifting the Exponent Lemma and I found that if $m|a+1$, $m$ is odd and $a+1$ is not a power of $2$, then $m|a^m+1$. But for the question $a+m \ |\ a^m+1 \ $, I cannot make any progress, especially the 2. question. Are there any ways to solve the questions ?

(Sorry, English is my second language)

Comment: For $a=2$ no such integer exists.

Comment: @Servaes Sorry, it's actualy $a>3$. I have edited it.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Also, what techniques have you tried / progress have you made? Have you, for example, found any such pairs $(a,m)$, or proven that none exist for any specific $a>3$?

Comment: I did not find a solution for $\ \ a=12\ \ $ yet

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut : Sorry, I have written it wrong, in fact $a$ is given in the first place, not "For all $a$'s". I have tried to use LTE, but it may not work. (Sorry, English is my second language)

Comment: Iterating to 10,000 on both a and m produces pairs: (4,9),  (4,477),  (4,1413),  (4,6105),  (5,9),  (5,308),  (6,5),  (6,95),  (6,1105),  (7,6),  (7,15),  (7,18),  (7,165),  (7,174),  (7,318),  (7,375),  (7,2346),  (7,2431),  (7,4195),  (7,4518),  (8,25),  (8,35),  (8,985),  (8,5411),  (8,8275),  (8,9065),  (9,49),  (10,3),  (10,9),  (10,81),  (10,1719),  (11,50),  (11,63),  (11,6150),  (11,6375),  (13,405),  (13,1785),  (13,3825),  (13,4620),  (13,9093),  (14,55),  (14,65),  (14,81),  (14,291),  (14,897),  (14,5945),  (14,7293),  (15,14),  (15,77),  (15,98),  (15,143), ...

Comment: @Servaes not true, when $a = 2$, $m = 49735$ works (but is the first such $m$), as does $m = 717025$

Comment: @Christopher That's a great find! I'll revisit my argument. How did you find this solution?

Comment: @Servaes an unsubtle computer search

Comment: After a few days improving my program, I found$$12+1\,022\,924\,329\mid12^{1\,022\,924\,329}+1$$