# Prove that infinitely many integers $n$ satisfy $(n+a)\mid(a^n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\gt3$. Prove that there exist infinitely
>   many positive integers $n$ satisfying $(n+a)\mid(a^n+1)$.

This problem was mentioned for the first time in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968838/an-a-1-divisible-by-n), so all the credits should go to [Drona](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/92987/drona). The author (wrongly, I think) thought that the two problems were equivalent. I made a comment about that but it went unnoticed because it was the last one in a pretty long chain. I asked Drona to post the original question but did not hear from him since then. I believe that this problem is too interesting to be left buried in some hidden comment, so I decided to post it here.

It's relatively easy to prove that $a$ and $n$ must be coprime. But apart from that simple fact I did not get much further.

Comment: For $a=12$, can you find _any_ qualifying positive integer value of $n$, other than $n=1$?

Comment: Unless you know the statement is true, to be fair to would-be solvers, you should state the problem as either a question (e.g., _must_ there be infinitely many . . . ?), or a conjecture, or a prove/disprove statement, rather than a claim.

Comment: Also, why did you skip the cases $a=2$, and $a=3$?

Comment: In the referenced post, Drona never claimed the problems were equivalent. What's true (as Drona surely knew) is that the two problems are related in the following way: If $a$ is a positive integer such that $k{\,\mid\,}(a^k - a + 1)$ for infinitely many positive integers $k$, then $(n+a){\,\mid\,}(a^n+1)$ for infinitely many positive integers $n$.

Comment: @quasi He started his problem with: "I have a problem, and it leads to the following problem..."

Comment: What he _mean't_ was that if he could solve that one with a "yes" answer, then he could solve his original one with a "yes" answer.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959285/does-there-exist-an-integer-m1-such-that-am-is-a-divisor-of-am1) the same problem?

Comment: I'm interested in the problem at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968838/an-a-1-divisible-by-n, not this problem. I did not say that the two problems were equal. This problem is only a consequence of the problem I mentioned. Do you understand?

Comment: @YongHaoNg It definitely is. Somehow MSE did not suggest an obvious duplicate.

Comment: @quasi $12+1\,022\,924\,329\mid12^{1\,022\,924\,329}+1$, found by Julián Aguirre.

Comment: So $a=12$ finally succumbed, but it held out for quite a while!

Comment: My prior point is still valid. Unless you actually know that a statement is true, it's misleading to state the problem as "Prove . . ."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this may not be a proper solution or a solution at all but I'll try my best. Sorry in advance.

If $ (a+n)|(a^n+1)$ then by long division we get the remainder $(-1)^kn^ka^{n-k} +1$ for each k times that we divide. When we keep on dividing then k finally becomes $n$. Then the remainder becomes $(-1)^nn^n+1$. Since $(a+n)|(a^n+1) \rightarrow (a+n)|((-1)^nn^n+1)$ in order for the remainder to vanish. The term $(-1)^nn^n+1$ is dependent only on n, and we can find its factors($x$) greater than $3+n$ where they exist. Then we have the desired values of $n$ for each $a = x-n$.

Comment: Basically, you have replaced the original problem with the following one: Prove that there exists $n$ such that $(-1)^nn^n+1$ has a factor greater than 3+n. It could be a way to proceed but it's still not a complete solution.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't make any argument except that "hey that's obvious, if you don't find such factors for the term, then choose another n".

Comment: Many terms definitely has such factors when n is odd. But I'm all out of arguments.

Comment: True, most numbers like $(-1)^nn^n+1$ have factors and for each factor you will get some value for $a$. But you cannot guarantee that every possible value of $a$ will be hit. Actually, you are proving that there is a solution for some values of $a$ but not for all of them. Don't get me wrong, it's still something :)

Comment: Yes, I realize the mistake. Should I delete the post?

Comment: No, no... It's not a full solution but it's a legitimate idea. It is possible that your equivalent statement is easier to prove than the original one. Someone could still find that inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

This is also not a proper solution but might be a good direction to follow. Suppose $a-1$ is not a power of 2 and is not a prime number. Let $s\geq 3$ be an odd prime factor of $a-1$ and $r=(a-1)/s \geq 2$. Suppose that $A=a^{r}+1$ has a prime factor $p$ greater than $\sqrt{A}$. Then $p>\sqrt{A}>a$. We claim that $n+a \mid a^n+1$, where $n=p-a>0$. One has, by Fermat's little theorem, that
$$a^n+1 \equiv a^{p-a}+1 \equiv a^{1-a}(a^{a-1}+1) \equiv a^{1-a}(a^{r}+1)B \equiv 0 \pmod p,$$
for some integer $B$.

The probability of a number $A$ having a prime factor greater than $\sqrt{A}$ is $\log 2$. So this argument proves the claim for at least 30 percent of numbers.